# I need suggesting for completring my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project where I have to make a script to show events on a webpage depending on the day I think I have most of it correct but it is not working properly here is the code I have so far

```
 var thisDate = new Date("October 12, 2018");
 var dateStr = thisDate.toLocaleDateString();

 var dateHTML = "<h2>" + dateStr + "</h2>";

 var thisDay = document.getElementById();
 insert.AdjacentHTML("unionToday") + dateHTML + innerHTML;
```

any tips or help would be appreciated `

I needed to declare a thisDate var containing the date Oct 12, 2018
then declare a var dateString with text of thisDate using local conventions
then declare dateHTML containing text string

### date

which I think I have done correctly 
the 2nd half is what I need help with which is create thisDay var containg the day of the week number from the thisDay var
then use the thisDay var as the parameter value call the getEvent() function to get the HTMLcode of that days events and staire that value in a var named eventHTML

and lastly apply the insertAdjacentHTML() method to the page element with the id unionToday insert the value of the dateHTML plus the eventHTML var before the end of the element contents

Comment: Could you give us a bit more details about what's the problem you run into? Please update your question with the details rather than adding them as a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for.

```js
var thisDate = new Date("October 12, 2018");
var dateStr = thisDate.toLocaleDateString();

var unionToday = "<div>some random text goes here</div>";

var dateHTML = "<h2>" + dateStr + "</h2>";

var thisDay = document.getElementById("data");
thisDay.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",unionToday+dateHTML);
```

```html
<span id="data">some text already present here</span>
```

You might wanna [see this and learn about insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) before using the above example as it may give you some ideas.